# Creating Multi-Index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I'm trying to use a multi-index to analyse my betting activity, here is a sample of some of the data.

| Date | Tipster | Bookie | Market | Stakes | Line | Odds | Returns | Profit | Reason | Event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Date 1 | Me | Bet365 | Overs | 50 | 2.5 | 1.9 | 0 | -50 | Injury | Event 1 |
| Date 2 | Me | Bet365 | SW | 100 |  | 2 | 200 | 100 | Hunch | Event 2 |
| Date 3 | Dave | Bet365 | Overs | 50 | 2.5 | 1.9 | 0 | -50 | Good Price | Event 3 |
| "" | "" | Betfair Exchange | Overs | 50 | 2.5 | 2 | 0 | -50 | "" | "" |
| Date 4 | Me | Betfair Exchange | Unders | 50 | 3.5 | 1.8 | 90 | 40 | Out of Line | Event 4 |
| "" | "" | "" | "" | 200 | 4.5 | 1.4 | 280 | 80 | "" | "" |
| Date 5 | Andy | Smarkets | SW | 100 |  | 3.7 | 0 | -100 | Weak Lineup | Event 5 |
| "" | "" | "" | Handicaps | 200 | 0.5 | 1.5 | 300 | 100 | "" | "" |
| "" | "" | Bet365 | DC | 200 |  | 1.45 | 290 | 90 | "" | "" |
| Date 6 | Me | Bet365 | Overs | 100 | 2.5 | 1. 9 | 0 | -100 | Injury | Event 6 |

As you can see sometimes on one event I will bet with multiple bookmakers, and on those bookmakers i may place multiple bets (for instance the 4th row where the first "Date" is blank is still a bet on event 3, and the 6th row is still a Betfair Exchange "Unders" bet, but on a different line.)

I tried setting a multi-index using

```
df.set_index(["Date","Tipster","Bookie","Line"],inplace = True)
```

but the 4th row isn't included into the Date 4 index, it's just a separate blank.

The same problem is encountered when I try to use group by

```
df.groupby(["Tipster"]).Profit.sum().toframe()
```

here it says the total profit for Andy and Dave is -100 and -50, where it should be 90 and -100 respectively.

I think the problem would be solved if I filled in the blanks with relevant event, bookie etc, but I feel like there is a better solution involving multi-indexes.

Any help would be great, thanks!

ps. is there a quick way to put a table in these questions? Took me an age to pop this one in using the markdown format.

Answer (score 0):

Do not conflate your internal and external data representations.  Fully populate your data frame (DF).  The DF is there to satisfy the computer, not to be human-readable.  If you want the table format you show above, then simply handle this with your display routine.  Do not expect your DF package to muck around for data you decided to put somewhere else.

As for showing your DF in a question, simply print it with the default Pandas display, paste it into your question, and format as code.

Comment: The data is in this format because It is easiest to enter quickly as often the situation requires speed. Will come up with some code to fill it in before I analyse, Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great; there are a lot of references here on Stack Overflow for propagating values through a data frame.